# Starting SecAstQFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified - error when starting secast

Tags: linux, security, asterisk, pbx

I'm receiving the below error when starting secast

service secast start
Starting SecAstQFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
[FAILED]

Has anyone run into this issue before? I'm running CentOS 6.5 with Asterisk 11

All config files appear to be in the correct location and there are no log files to review.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you modify your post - perhaps enclosing the pasted lines into code braces? The lack of newlines makes this tough to read. Also are these lines onscreen or in the log file?  Could you paste the lines from the SecAst log file, from service start to end (including where the error appears)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the SecAst package you downloaded is not corrupt?  (Did you compare the md5sum of your file to that on the [www.generationd.com](http://www.generationd.com) website?).  Any warnings on untarring/unzipping?

What is the filename setting in the [logging] section of secst.conf?  Does the path exist?  Do you have write permissions all the way to that file name?